# Issues when add cordova to my existing ios project: cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ionic-framework

I tried to add cordova project into my existing ios project. I can successful compile the app.   But when I run it, I got this exceptions for cordovaSettingForKey.

-[__NSDictionaryM cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x147052a30

EXCEPTION THROW: -[__NSDictionaryM cordovaSettingForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x147052a30

Anyone knows how to resolve the problem

Here is the header file

```
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVCommandDelegateImpl.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVCommandQueue.h>

@interface MainViewController : CDVViewController

@end

@interface MainCommandDelegate : CDVCommandDelegateImpl
@end

@interface MainCommandQueue : CDVCommandQueue 
@end
```

Here is the .m file

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation MainViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle*)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Uncomment to override the CDVCommandDelegateImpl used
        // _commandDelegate = [[MainCommandDelegate alloc] initWithViewController:self];
        // Uncomment to override the CDVCommandQueue used
        // _commandQueue = [[MainCommandQueue alloc] initWithViewController:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Uncomment to override the CDVCommandDelegateImpl used
        // _commandDelegate = [[MainCommandDelegate alloc] initWithViewController:self];
        // Uncomment to override the CDVCommandQueue used
        // _commandQueue = [[MainCommandQueue alloc] initWithViewController:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // View defaults to full size.  If you want to customize the view's size, or its subviews (e.g. webView),
    // you can do so here.

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return [super shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

/* Comment out the block below to over-ride */

/*
- (UIWebView*) newCordovaViewWithFrame:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return[super newCordovaViewWithFrame:bounds];
}
*/

@end

@implementation MainCommandDelegate

/* To override the methods, uncomment the line in the init function(s)
   in MainViewController.m
 */

#pragma mark CDVCommandDelegate implementation

- (id)getCommandInstance:(NSString*)className
{
    return [super getCommandInstance:className];
}

- (NSString*)pathForResource:(NSString*)resourcepath
{
    return [super pathForResource:resourcepath];
}

@end

@implementation MainCommandQueue

/* To override, uncomment the line in the init function(s)
   in MainViewController.m
 */
- (BOOL)execute:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    return [super execute:command];
}

@end
```

Here is how I call it

```
MainViewController * layer = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Thanks

-Emmy

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you figure out the solution?

Answer (score 10):

try adding -ObjC to your target's "Other Linker Flags".   Note: the cordova docs say it is the "-Obj-C" flag, which will not resolve the issue.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/webview.html

Comment: When I add this flag, I get another error:

ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: This -ObjC should be added to your project's target(s), instead of Cordova project's target.